# Moving data from Snowflake to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The Kafka => Snowflake path is well covered by the Snowflake connector (and other tools). 
What about moving the data in the other direction?

Has anyone used the generic JDBC source Kafka connector with Snowflake?

The general idea is to have the content of some Snowflake tables made available in Kafka.
Kind of a change data capture / snapshot run at some big enough intervals (like one hour / one day).

Any experience to share? Other ideas?

Comment: I'm interested why you'd have this pattern; can you not take the data that's loaded to Snowflake and load it to Kafka too? Or load to Kafka and then to Snowflake?

Comment: @Kirby if we go about the JDBC Kafka connector I will consider it. I did play with them 1 year ago when they were released; it could be a smart way to extrapolate deltas to move to Kafka, but they not move the data by themselves.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt data will come from Kafka into SF (from different sources) and some new data will be calculated inside SF out of it. To make the calculated data available to all the ecosystem (micro-services and other applications reading from Kafka) through the standard integration. Also SF is a columnar / reporting DB, not an operational one, so the speed to answer to tiny queries is not much smaller than bigger ones and it is "too slow" for a micro-service to wait half a second for few rows that it could get in milliseconds from an operational DB or Kafka.

Comment: Makes sense. One last question - the calculations being done in Snowflake, could they be done with Kafka Streams/ksqlDB instead since the data is already in Kafka?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt most probably yes, but if you are building a data lake and a data warehouse on top of it inside Snowflake... even if you know equally well how to code in both ways I feel it is much simpler to do the calculations on the DW side. First you do not have to deploy (and maintain) anything extra to do the calculation and then you have all the data you need with all the time depth, the scalability of the platform and the data is already there for the business users to query too. ...TBC

Comment: @RobinMoffatt ... The other way (KStream / KSQL) you have to deploy somewhere some micro-service that does the calculation joining multiple streams hoping all the data you need is in Kafka, put the result back in another Kafka channel and then stream it up to the DW. This extra complexity makes sense if the calculation NEEDs to be available in real-time (less than one second up to a few minutes). 
Snowflake /DW route is simpler, but not suited in cases where the result is needed in less than a few minutes (five being probably the hard limit, 15 to one hour the grey zone).

Comment: @RobMcZag - How did you solve this problem? We are also in same boat in regards to snowflake to kafka

Comment: JDBC Source connector can definitely work with Snowflake using their [JDBC driver](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc.html)

Answer (score 4):

If someone is still looking for an answer, this is possible using Kafka Connect JDBC Source Connector. [Here](https://medium.com/@pandeysudhendu/streaming-data-from-snowflake-to-kafka-ed76ce0400c2) is the step-by-step guide.

Here is the high-level flow:

- Create a Snowflake Instance.
- Create a Kafka Environment
- Setting up Confluent Kafka connect JBDC Source connector.
- Installing Snowflake JDBC driver.
- Run the Kafka Connector and do a sanity check.
- Final step: to see if change data is getting captured!

Comment: Thanks for this, I wish you had written that blog 2 weeks earlier then I could have saved some time :D
But just what kind of ordering did you use with your connector properties in the blog? It's not alphabetical, and it's not by "topic" (for example all the transform properties are distributed), I find that extremely hard to read.

Comment: I don't think I specifically followed any order. What I know is that the Kafka connector reorders it once you save it, so it might be the connector's default behavior.

Comment: I have snowflake SSO signin (no password). They way I signin to snowflake from DataGrip is via Authenticator: externalbrowser. I cannot find a way to connect the kafka-connector source with similar way. Or can we use pub-priv key-pair to connect with kafka source ? plz help.

Comment: Went through your article today. I believe the title should not contain word `Streaming` as its based on pooling mechanism. This connector runs SELECT query on fixed interval and sents deltas to kafka.

Answer (score 1):

While its possible using Kafka Connect JDBC Source Connector as suggested by @Sudhendu. Another approach is to use Kafka streams + S3 Source Kafka Connector.

1. Setup Kafka cluster
2. Create Snowflake integration with S3
3. Attach streams objects with your desired table
4. capture table deltas into stream object and send to S3 using the `COPY INTO` command.
5. S3 Source Kafka Connector listens on new files landing into s3 bucket and sends them to kafka.

This process can be productionized by wrapping the snowflake scripts inside a [stored procedure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview) and ran on scheduled bases using [snowflake tasks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro).

**Things  to keep in mind:**

1. S3 source kafka connector also operates on polling mechanism. It scans s3 bucket desired location to check for new files, at a fixed interval. Frequent polling on a big s3 bucket will cost you more on read operations. So keep the polling interval at a reasonable rate.
2. This is not an event-driven real-time solution, as kafka streams are query based CDC (and not log based CDC). Which means we have to query the stream object every time to check for deltas.
3. Snowflake Streams offer several cost-related benefits. Firstly, streams fetch new data only when changes occur in the source table, minimizing unnecessary data retrieval. Secondly, any logic implemented on the stream consumes data only when it is available, rather than continuously consuming resources. This ensures efficient utilization of credits, as they are consumed only when there is data in the stream, saving costs when there is none.

Read more here: https://maxcotec.com/learning/snowflake-streams-to-kafka-topic/

Or watch: https://youtu.be/nTq64FYCOU0