Is it possible to use dbt to transfer data from Snowflake to Kafka topics?
I'm working on a project where I need to transfer data from Snowflake tables to Apache Kafka topics. I'm not familiar with dbt and I'm wondering if it's possible to use dbt to facilitate this data transfer process.
If it's possible to use dbt for transferring data from Snowflake to Kafka, is there an example of how to define Kafka as destination? If not, what would be the recommended alternatives for this data transfer task, which preferably should run in batch mode?
Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

DBT is not the right tool for this. DBT helps you generate SQL or Spark code using macro type languages. It's not an inter-service tool, it's for transforming in-place data.... although enhancements are always being used. You need something that takes data from Snowflake and puts fires it off to Kafka. Maybe you could start by reading this. https://medium.com/snowflake/streaming-data-from-snowflake-to-kafka-ed76ce0400c2

Reading that article, you basically set up Kafka, then install a snowflake JDBC driver in Kafka, then get Kafka to connect to Snowflake and monitor for changes. So your first step is to install Kafka and make sure it can connect to Snowflake. This setup is a "pull" from snowflake rather than a push from Snowflake, which I mentioned in my prior comment

Voting to close this question as I think everything is covered on the older one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62444348/moving-data-from-snowflake-to-kafka. Please start a new question if something specific is not covered there.

Does this answer your question? Moving data from Snowflake to Kafka
